# Looping through range and check value (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a simple VBA code to loop through a range to check for a particular value, if it is true, then it would switch a boolean trigger to False.

However, my code does not work. Even though I have placed '12345' somewhere in the range, it still returns Infochk = True.

Code

```
Dim InfoChk As Boolean
InfoChk = True
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row
For i = 7 To LR
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .Cells(i, 6).Value = "12345" Then
            MsgBox ("gotcha")
            InfoChk = False
            Exit For
        End If
    End With
Next i
MsgBox (InfoChk)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have used LastRow variable and in the loop you used LR .. Try using LastRow instead

Comment: Oh my god.... Such a noob error. Thanks man. Fix it up and add it to answer and I will mark it correct.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Agreed and noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LastRow:

```
Sub poiuy()
    Dim InfoChk As Boolean
    InfoChk = True
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 7 To LastRow
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            If .Cells(i, 6).Value = "12345" Then
                MsgBox ("gotcha")
                InfoChk = False
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    MsgBox (InfoChk)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: OP `with` statement isn't really needed. Adds two extra lines of code.

Comment: @PGCodeRider  **You are absolutely correct!**  My goal in responding is to get working code with a minimum of changes to the Poster's code.

Comment: @PGCodeRider - can you please tell me how it is not needed? How would code look like? Thanks

Comment: Nuke the 2 with statements and just put worksheets(“Sheet2”).cells(i,6)